# Preventing label and image overlapping

Tags: .net, algorithm, d3.js

I try to find a solution for displaying labels on the image without overlapping. I mean overlapping not only labels with each other but with picture also.

For this purpose I have found some d3 plug-ins like [d3-labeler](https://github.com/tinker10/D3-Labeler) and [d3fc-label-layout](https://d3fc.io/api/label-layout-api.html).

The plug-ins can disable overlapping of labels and work very well.

As you can see on the screenshot the red text overlaps picture (black lines):
[image]

Can I prevent image overlapping using [d3-labeler](https://github.com/tinker10/D3-Labeler) or [d3fc-label-layout](https://d3fc.io/api/label-layout-api.html) or something else???